# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error when using WebViewJavascriptBridge

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm a very new iOS developer (I only started a few days ago), and I'm trying to utilize the [WebViewJavascriptBridge class](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge/) with a UIWebView that I've got on my Storyboard. Whenever I try to use it, I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The trouble lines seem to be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WebViewJavascriptBridge* bridge = [WebViewJavascriptBridge bridgeForWebView:webView handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {
        NSLog(@"Received message from javascript: %@", data);
        responseCallback(@"Right back atcha");
    }];

    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s", path, "htdocs/index.html"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    [webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL]];
}
```

To be exact, the last line. If I don't make that request, I don't get the error. I've tried it with a UIWebView created just in Objective-C, and still gotten the error, although maybe I did it wrong.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Method for storing webView is this code + reference outlet.

```
@interface mcViewController : UIViewController
    {
        IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually occurs when you've tried to access an objective C object that has been deallocated. I can't see a problem from the code you've posted, so actual issue may be elsewhere. Check your properties - is everything that should be `strong` actually declared that way?

Please [enable zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) to get information about what type of object it is that has been accessed after deallocation.

Where is `webView` declared, and how?

I take it you're using ARC?

**Update**

Ok, I think I see the problem now.

You're declaring your troublesome object as a local variable:

```
WebViewJavascriptBridge* bridge = ...
```

This means that once that function scope is left (i.e. the end of the function is reached), that object can be deallocated, and is.

Try declaring a strong property for your `bridge` instead. Then it won't be deallocated prematurely. For example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebViewJavascriptBridge* bridge;
```

Then later in your code:

```
self.bridge = ... // the creation code
```

And once you've finished with your object, don't forget to deallocate it:

```
self.bridge = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. This was reported '[WebViewJavascriptBridge respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d5a97e0' now to figure out how to debug that...also I updated my answer with my code for how webView is being declared.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change to use this library.

[SDBridgeOC](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeOC)

```
 self.bridge.consolePipeBlock = ^(id  _Nonnull water) {
        NSLog(@"Next line is javascript console.log------>>>>");
        NSLog(@"%@",water);
    };
```

This can easy to get javascript console.log.

Also have Swift language Version.

[SDBridgeSwift](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeSwift)

```
bridge.consolePipeClosure = { water in
         guard let jsConsoleLog = water else {
             print("Javascript console.log give native is nil!")
              return
         }
         print("Next line is Javascript console.log----->>>>>>>")
         print(jsConsoleLog)
      }
```